How do i make whole screen scrollable only lazyGrid is scrollable
if i make it lazyColumn then i get error saying infinite length and i am not able to make it scrollable and only using column does not do anything
i tried lazyColumn as it will scroll whole page but not able to as it gives me error then i tried using column with vertical scroll, same result as before
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    navController: NavHostController
) {
    var searchText = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier,
        topBar = {
            HomeTopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier,
                onCartClick = {
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(navController)
        }
    ) {innerPadding->
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = Color.White) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
            ) {
                ProductSearchBar(searchText)
                CategoryGrid(navController)
                BannerCarousel(modifier = Modifier)
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    LazyVerticalGrid(
                        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                    ) {
                        repeat(10) {
                            item {
                                OutlinedCard(
                                    onClick = {}
                                ) {
                                    Column {
                                        Box {
                                            Image(
                                                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.iphonee),
                                                contentDescription = "Iphone"
                                            )
                                        }
                                        Box {

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}


Do I understand this right, you want the whole screen scroll as one, including the ProductSearchBar and CategoryGrid and BannerCarousel and LazyVerticalGrid?

@BenjyTec yes whole screen but i am not able to do soo... i changed column to lazyColumn and  gave lazyVerticalGrid some height and CategoryGrid too then i  did not got any error

If you want each section to be scrollable individually, then you need to give each section a fixed height, as you already found out. If you want the whole thing to be scrollable at once, you can try to put everything into a single LazyVerticalGrid (except for any TopAppBar) and for TopAppBar, you can specify a scrollBehavior to let it collapse when scrolling.

@BenjyTec i did not use lazyVerticlGrid as i was having 2 columns so i used lazyColumn and used height property thanks for help

Make the column as verticalScroll and another change is you have fixed your item height based on the item height calculate the LazyVerticalGrid height. This will resolve the issue.
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
    //navController: NavHostController
) {
    var searchText = remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    Scaffold(
        modifier = Modifier,
        topBar = {
            HomeTopAppBar(
                modifier = Modifier,
                onCartClick = {
                }
            )
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomNavigationBar(navController)
        }
    ) {innerPadding->
        Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = Color.White) {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(innerPadding)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
            ) {
                ProductSearchBar(searchText)
                CategoryGrid(navController)
                BannerCarousel(modifier = Modifier)
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                ) {
                    LazyVerticalGrid(
                        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).height(( 10.times(70).dp))
                    ) {
                        repeat(10) {
                            item {
                                OutlinedCard(
                                    modifier = Modifier.height(70.dp),
                                    onClick = {}
                                ) {
                                    Column {
                                        Box {
                                            Image(
                                                painter = painterResource(R.drawable.iphonee),
                                                contentDescription = "Iphone"
                                            )
                                        }
                                        Box {

                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}

